# Slim 3 htaccess to redirect to public folder.

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, my Slim project is stored in `localhost/projects/applications/file hosting/src/`. My project works when I setup a virtual host via MAMP with the root set to the `public` folder. I'm trying to make it so I can access the "raw" URL for the project and have my public folder as the root. I've tried adding an `.htaccess` file inside the `src` directory with various rewrites and conditions but all seem to error out the program.

How would I go about setting up an `.htaccess` file to set my public directory as the root when I visit `http://localhost/Projects/Applications/File%20Hosting/src/`?

Comment: Does anyone know how that one works? Having the same issues.